# Excel VBA - Sum 2 sets of cells with a loop

Tags: vba, excel

Simple question, yet I can't get it to work. I simply need to sum 2 sets of cells and paste the totals in a different column.

For example, I need to add the time value G4 and time value in G14 and paste the sum in B25. This should loop down to G10+G20 and paste into B31.

I know how easy it is with a simple excel function, but I need it in VBA terms, and ideally in a loop, not the recorder version of code.

```
Range("B25") = "=SUM(" & Range(G4, G14) & ")"
```

[image]

Comment: While posting the screenshot of your data, always include the Row# and Columns letters.

Comment: `Range("B25") = "=SUM(" & Range("G4", "G14").address & ")"`

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.  @Nathan_Sav, and to loop through?  I need to add G4 thru G10, to G14 thru G20, and paste in B25 thru B31, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub AddValues()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer

    j = 4
    k = 14

    For i = 25 To 31
        Range("B" & i) = "=SUM(G" & j & ",G" & k & ")"
        j = j + 1
        k = k + 1
    Next i

End Sub
```

Edit: Thanks @Steve for the hint

Comment: Thanks David.  However, did not quite work.  It added G4 and G14 correctly and pasted in B25.  But then it pasted ((G5+G15)+B25) into B26.  Should of course just be G5+G15 into B26.

Comment: In a worksheet formula `=SUM(G4,G14)` is the same as `=G4+G14`, but the code here is equivalent to `=SUM(G4:G14)`. I think you might want the relevant line in the code to be: `Range("B" & i) = "=SUM(G" & j & ",G" & k & ")"`

Comment: Sorry, the quote marks are confusing, so I had to edit that a few times!